# arranging div class tiles vertically

Tags: html, css, class

I am trying to place the class called `tile` with a few other bits around it so that it is a vertical list.  The tiles are of different sizes and don't seem to list vertically. I also want to put some text alongside it but not sure how.  The first tile has a label inside it called "Overview", but the others I want to place some text to the right of the tile without messing up the vertical alignment.

```html
<div id="sidebar-company">

  <a class="tileSB bg-darkBlue animated six flipInX" data-click="transform">
    <div class="brand">
      <div class="text-center">
        <p class="fg-white">Overview</p></div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="tileSB half bg-darkBlue animated seven flipInX" data-click="transform">
    <div class="tile-content icon">
      <img src="images/mthc/arrowRight.png">

    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="tileSB half bg-darkBlue animated eight flipInX" data-click="transform">
    <div class="tile-content icon">
      <img src="images/mthc/arrowRight.png">
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="tileSB half bg-darkBlue animated nine flipInX" data-click="transform">
    <div class="tile-content icon">
      <img src="images/mthc/arrowRight.png">
    </div>
  </a>

</div> <!-- End tile group -->
```

How can I do this in CSS?

Comment: wouldn't using divs instead of anchor tags make them be vertical by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do either:

Display them as a block - should take up a new line:

```css
a.tileSB {
  display: block
}
```

Float and clear all the elements:

```css
a.tileSB {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```css
.tileSB {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-company">

  <a class="tileSB bg-darkBlue animated six flipInX" data-click="transform">
    <div class="brand">
      <div class="text-center">
        <p class="fg-white">Overview</p></div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="tileSB half bg-darkBlue animated seven flipInX" data-click="transform">
    <div class="tile-content icon">
      <img src="images/mthc/arrowRight.png"> - Text 2
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="tileSB half bg-darkBlue animated eight flipInX" data-click="transform">
    <div class="tile-content icon">
      <img src="images/mthc/arrowRight.png"> - Text 3
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="tileSB half bg-darkBlue animated nine flipInX" data-click="transform">
    <div class="tile-content icon">
      <img src="images/mthc/arrowRight.png"> - Text 4
    </div>
  </a>

</div> <!-- End tile group -->
```

Comment: yup that one worked ! I was missing the a.tileSB and just trying to change tileSB

Comment: although the suggestion of where the text should go just put it inside the tile itself.... i guess that is because it is inside the div still.... I just hope I can align the text to the right by putting it inside a div that is defined as "inline" instead of block.

Comment: i answered my own sub-question ..... creating another div outside the /a worked great thanks for your help mate !

Answer (score 1):

Give to all your `a` anchor elements a CSS property of `display:block`

```
#sidebar-company a{
   display:block;
}
```

Block elements are displayed vertically by default since they take up all the available space

Comment: didn't work the tiles arrange from left to right horizontally even if i give "tileSB" the attribute you mentioned

Comment: You have other CSS that messes with them - Head over to a tutorial otherwise you won't get far even if it does work this time